# When calling a get method in Android Studio it returns a zero value even though earlier it was an int

Tags: java, android

This is the code for one of my methods that select a random value and assign it to question1select. This seems to work fine until i try and use a get method to which it always returns a zero, even though it should not be because println said it had a value.

```
public void selectQuestions()
{
    System.out.println("selectQuestions is running");
    question1select = randomNumber();
    question2select = randomNumber();
    question3select = randomNumber();
    question4select = randomNumber();
    question5select = randomNumber();
    System.out.println("it has selected numbers and is now testing them");
    if (question1select == question2select)
    {
        selectQuestions();
    }
    else if (question1select == question3select)
    {
        selectQuestions();
    }
    else if (question1select == question4select)
    {
        selectQuestions();
    }
    else if (question1select == question5select)
    {
        selectQuestions();
    }
    else if (question2select == question3select)
    {
        selectQuestions();
    }
    else if (question2select == question4select)
    {
        selectQuestions();
    }
    else if (question2select == question5select)
    {
        selectQuestions();
    }
    else if (question3select == question4select)
    {
        selectQuestions();
    }
    else if (question3select == question5select)
    {
        selectQuestions();
    }
    else if (question4select == question5select)
    {
        selectQuestions();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(" the value of question1select is " +question1select);
        System.out.println(" the value of question2select is " +question2select);
        System.out.println(" the value of question3select is " +question3select);
        System.out.println(" the value of question4select is " +question4select);
        System.out.println(" the value of question5select is " +question5select);
        page1questionaccessor access = new page1questionaccessor();
        access.questionAnswer();
    }
}


public int getNumber1()
{
    System.out.println(" the value of question1select in getNumber1 is " +question1select);
    return question1select;
}
public int getNumber2()
{
    return question2select;
}
public int getNumber3()
{
    return question3select;
}
public int getNumber4()
{
    return question4select;
}
public int getNumber5()
{
    return question5select;
}
```

This is what calls the getNumber1 method, quick note- all of the if statements are the copy/ pasted and I don't believe them to be the problem.

```
public void questionAnswer()
{
    System.out.println("it should be testing number values");
    questionchanger change;
    System.out.println("1");
    change = new questionchanger();
    System.out.println("2");
    int x = change.getNumber1();
    System.out.println("4");
    System.out.println("x = " +x);

    if (x == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question1();

    }
    else if (x == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question2();
    }
    else if (x == 3)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question3();
    }
    else if (x == 4)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question4();
    }
    else if (x == 5)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question5();
    }
    else if (x == 6)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question6();
    }
    else if (x == 7)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question7();
    }
    else if (x == 8)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question8();
    }
    else if (x == 9)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question9();
    }
    else if (x == 10)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question10();
    }
    else if (x == 11)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question11();
    }
    else if (x == 12)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question12();
    }
    else if (x == 13)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question13();
    }

    else if (x == 14)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question14();
    }
    else if (x == 15)
    {
        System.out.println("a question should be accsing");
        question_answers question;
        question = new question_answers();
        question.question15();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("an imposible number was selected");
    }

}
```

}

Here is the logcat

```
10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ 1371012it has selected numbers and is now testing them

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ the value of question1select is 1

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ the value of question2select is 3

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ the value of question3select is 7

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ the value of question4select is 10

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ the value of question5select is 12

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ it should be testing number values

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ 1

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ 2

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ the value of question1select in getNumber1 is 0

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ 4

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ x = 0

10-04 15:46:43.196    9686-9686/com.example.michael.trivia I/System.out﹕ an imposible number was selected
```

Comment: in your code

    change = new questionchanger();
    System.out.println("2");
    int x = change.getNumber1();

you are creating a **NEW** `questionchanger` object, and immediately calling `getNumber1()` on it, which returns the initial value of `question1select` which is 0. May be you intended to use the existing object ?

Comment: That's exactly what I intended to do. How would I do that, I tried extending the second class, but that still returned zero. So how would I call a method of an existing object. And thanks a ton ashoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be simpler if I could comment, but I only have 1 rep, so... Yeah...

**Short Answer**

Based on the code you are showing, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong. My best guess would be an issue with variable scope or maybe even inheritance.

**Long Answer**

Is this all of your code? You should know, if you don't already, that when an integer is initialized but not set to a value, it defaults to zero, like so:

```
private static int question1select; //this would equal 0
```

Now, I can see that you are clearly setting it to a number through:

```
question1select = randomNumber();
```

In this same method, you go on to print the value of question1select to the logcat. It works. However, when you print it using another method later, it shows that it has reset back to 0.

As this isn't all of your code, I can't be certain. However, I do think that you may be initializing the same variable, question1select, multiple times, just in different scopes. You may be initializing it at the beginning of the class globally like so:

```
public class yourClassName{
    private static int question1select;
    ...
```

and then again in a local scope, such as the selectQuestions method:

```
public void selectQuestions(){
    private static int question1select;
    ...
```

Then, when you go to change the value of question1select using the randomNumber() method, it will maybe change the local one, but not the global one, leaving the global one at zero. Finally, when you try to print the new value from another class using the getNumber1() method, that method might be set to retrieve the global one instead, which is still at 0.

Like I said, this is only my best guess based on what I see.

Comment: Only commenting down here because I don't have enough rep to comment on the OP. Ashoke is right, however. What you should do is in the questionchanger class, you should define the question1select, question2select, etc... variables as "public static int question1select;" and so on. Then, as they are public, you don't have to call any get methods. Just do questionchanger.question1select to make a reference to it. Again, make sure you define it static so that it can be part of the class and not only part of instances of the class.